# Name not defined in a for loop

Tags: pandas

I have an excel file with 4 sheets and I'd like like to assign the first three sheets to different dataframe. I encounter a NameError in running the following code. How could it be fixed?

```
import pandas as pd 

for i in range(0,3):
    example[i] = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx',sheet_name = i)
```

> NameError: name 'example' is not defined

Comment: Put `example={}` before your for loop

Answer (score 2):

That's not a pandas specific question, but a general python question.
You accessed variable example, that was not defined before. It is not created implicitely when you do example[i]= (in fact the interpreter could not possibly know what kind of object example should be, it could as well be a dictionary).
The following should work (at least if your sheets are found using the index):

```
example= list()
for i in range(3): 
    example.append(pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx',sheet_name = i))
```

Here you create variable example by assign a list to it. In the loop you append the DataFrames to the example list.

Or even:

```
example= [pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx',sheet_name = i) for i in range(3)]
```

This is called a list comprehension. The result is the same as with the first method. Its just a bit shorter, and many pythonists like this kind of stuff.
I'd recommend you to look for a python tutorial. Here you can find [some recommended](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) tutorials. You will catch it up very quickly.